# scalajs-react: How to have multiline text field from a Seq in state object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scala.js, scalajs-react

I am working in a scalajs-react application. One of the UI field I have is an input field for multiline text, and it is mapped to a property of state object.
State object definition:

```
case class Person(name: String, addresses: Seq[String])
```

I have corresponding UI field for addresses as:

```
 <.label("Addresses:",
              <.input(^.`type` := "text", ^.cls := "form-control",
                ^.value := person.addresses.mkString("\n"), ^.onChange ==> updateAddresses))

def updateAddresses(event: ReactEventFromInput): Callback = {
    val updatedAddresses = event.target.value.split("\\\\n").toSeq // based on some google search
    $.modState(prev => prev.copy(addresses = updatedAddresses))
  }
```

But seems it doesn't work. I am not able to add a newline entry on UI.

How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You have to you `textarea` html tag for multiline text input. (see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)

This works:

```
<.label("Addresses:",
          <.textarea(^.`type` := "text", ^.cls := "form-control",
            ^.value := person.addresses.mkString("\n"), ^.onChange ==> updateAddresses))
```